# ldd does not find shared object and findes it at the same time

Tags: c++, c, linux, ldd

I was trying to deploy project with linuxdeployqt and when I run it with this command
`linuxdeployqt ./installer-base-temp/TargetX -bundle-non-qt-libs -qmldir="../source/" -extra-plugins=sqldrivers,iconengines,mediaservice -always-overwrite -unsupported-allow-new-glibc`
it shows the following error

```
ERROR: ldd outputLine: "libsamba-debug-samba4.so => not found"
ERROR: for binary: "/usr/lib64/samba/libsamba-modules-samba4.so"
ERROR: Please ensure that all libraries can be found by ldd. Aborting.
```

The strange thing is that when I run `ldd /usr/lib64/samba/libsamba-modules-samba4.so`
this is what I get

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc295ea000)
    libsamba-util.so.0 => /lib64/libsamba-util.so.0 (0x00007fb854716000)
    libsamba-errors.so.1 => /lib64/libsamba-errors.so.1 (0x00007fb8545ca000)
    libsamba-debug-samba4.so => not found
    libtalloc.so.2 => /lib64/libtalloc.so.2 (0x00007fb8545bd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb8543bc000)
    libgenrand-samba4.so => /usr/lib64/samba/libgenrand-samba4.so (0x00007fb8543b5000)
    libsocket-blocking-samba4.so => /usr/lib64/samba/libsocket-blocking-samba4.so (0x00007fb8543b0000)
    libsamba-debug-samba4.so => /usr/lib64/samba/libsamba-debug-samba4.so (0x00007fb8543a3000)
    libtime-basic-samba4.so => /usr/lib64/samba/libtime-basic-samba4.so (0x00007fb85439e000)
...
```

So *ldd* actually finds *libsamba-debug-samba4.so* to be located at */usr/lib64/samba/libsamba-debug-samba4.so*, but at the same time it does not find it.
I have already tired to reinstall the package with `sudo dnf reinstall samba-client-libs` and after that run `ldconfig`, moreover I have tried to run it after removing */etc/ld.so.cache*. It had no effect.
I am running Fedora 36 Workstation, with kernel version 5.17.13-300.fc36.x86_64.
Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: No, `ldd` does not find it `"libsamba-debug-samba4.so => not found"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 5 lines below there is `libsamba-debug-samba4.so => /usr/lib64/samba/libsamba-debug-samba4.so (0x00007fb8543a3000)`. So it does not find at first, but they it finds

Comment: My apologies, I must be getting blind in both eyes in my old age `:)`.  It looks like that is intended (or at least not your error). I just did `ldd /usr/lib64/samba/libsamba-modules-samba4.so` and got the same output. (samba/libsamba 4.16.2). So this is either a bug or your error may lie elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh ok, thank you. I have added /usr/lib64/samba/ with ldconfig, it seems to work now. I just understand why this happens. The weird part is it used to work find and even after I downgrade the package it does not work. Maybe i should open issue on libsamba page.

Comment: I'd ask the question on the samba list first. `samba@lists.samba.org`. The will look at it and tell you if a bug report is needed (and what is needed in the bug report, e.g. level-10 logs and/or tcpdump/wireshark traces between the hosts). If this is a packaging issue (which it sounds like if it is a bug), then simply reporting it is likely all that is needed. You can subscribe to the Samba list at [lists.samba.org Mailing Lists](https://lists.samba.org/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for help. I would do that.